# How can i toggle device screen cast option from a progressive web app when a button click? Is it possible

Tags: progressive-web-apps, screencast

Is it possible to turn on device screencast option from a progressive web app?

Comment: On Mobile (what OS?), Desktop of both? Screencast app or to something else?

Comment: only on mobile (both iOs and Android). It's a  video streaming web app.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for you to implement that 100% by yourself from within the browser sandbox. It could possibly be done with a chrome extension manually added by the user.

Comment: @Mathias thank you for the answer